# Sum of first n numbers and 2-element subsets

Tags: math

I know it's not strictly a programming question but computer scientists might know the answer. why is the sum of the first n non-negative numbers equal to the number of 2-element subsets?

Comment: Try asking here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should edit your question; as antonakos' answer shows, the sum of the first n-1 number is equal to the number of 2-element subsets in {1..n}

Answer (score 5):

So what you are asking is: why is `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n - 1` equal to the number of ways in which 2 elements out of `n` can be selected.

Imagine a complete graph with `n` nodes (every node of the graph is connected to every other node). The number of 2-element subsets is then equal to the number of edges of the graph.

Let the nodes be `v1, v2, ..., vn`. To construct the complete graph, connect `v1` to `v2, ..., vn` (n-1 edges), then connect `v2` to `v3, ..., vn` (n-2 edges), and so on up to `vn` that need not be connected to any more nodes. Thus the number of edges is thus `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 0` which is exactly equal to the first sum we introduced.

A less intuitive explanation is simply to note that `0 + 1 + ... + n-1 = [(0 + n-1) + (1 + n-2) + ... + (n-1 + 0)] / 2 = n * (n - 1) / 2` and that the formula for the number of k-combinations `n! / (k! * (n-k)!) = n! / (2! * (n-2)!) = (n * (n - 1)) / 2!` gives the same thing for `k = 2`.

Comment: Good answer! And nice work interpreting the incorrect wording of the question.

Comment: Good answer. Anyway i prefer strict proofs (last paragraph from your answer) instead of long explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It's not.  1 + 2 + 3 = 6.  The number of 2-element subsets in that set is 3.